# Rotation in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: matrices, geometry

Let $E_1:=\{(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in \mathbb{R}^n : x_n = 0\}$ be a hyperplane and let $E_2$ be any hyperplane that goes through the origin. I want to find a rigid motion $A: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $A(E_2)=E_1.$ Is the following procedure correct?

Since $E_2$ goes through the origin, it is a $(n-1)$-dimensional subspace. By Gram-Schmidt we can find a orthonormal system $(v_1,\ldots,v_{n-1})$ such that $E_2=\langle v_1,\ldots,v_{n-1}\rangle$. Let $w:= v_1 \times \ldots \times v_{n-1}$ (cross product) be the vector that is orthogonal to $v_1,\ldots,v_{n-1}.$
Then $A$ is given by $$x \mapsto\begin{pmatrix}\mid &  \mid&\cdots  & \mid\\
w &  v_1 & \ldots & v_{n-1}\\
\mid & \mid&\ldots&  \mid  \end{pmatrix}^{-1}x.$$

Is $A$ the correct rotation?

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to MSE. Your argument is almost correct, but there's a problem in your definition for $w$: cross product is only defined for vectors in $\mathbb R^3$!

So, how do we find this vector $w$ that is orthogonal to $(v_1, \cdots, v_n)$, the orthonormal basis of the plane? One solution is via orthogonal projection. Namely, choose any vector $w'$ not in the hyperplane, and subtract off its parallel components in the directions of $v_1, \dots, v_n$ to make it perpendicular to all of them. Then, your matrix $A$ will work.